# How to get content of an ArrayList to show in JavaFX GUI

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

I am trying to make a Pizza Ordering System in JavaFx using a TableView in the GUI. I finally got it to work, so I wanted to share my code if anyone else have trouble with showing the content of an ArrayList. Now I'll do layout stuff to make the TableView fit the Scene. If anyone has any suggestions on that, fell free to share :)

```
  package pizzaorderingsystem;

  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
  import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
  import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
  import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
  import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  public class PizzaOrderingSystem extends Application {

    private Stage window;
    private TableView<MenuItem> tableView;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }       

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Pizza ordering system");

    //Name column
    TableColumn<MenuItem, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name"); 
    nameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    //Price column
    TableColumn<MenuItem, Double> priceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Price"); 
    priceColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

    tableView = new TableView<>();
    tableView.setItems(getMenuItem());
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, priceColumn);

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(tableView);


    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();

    }

  public ObservableList<MenuItem> getMenuItem(){
    ObservableList<MenuItem> menuItems = 
  FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    menuItems.add(new Pizza("Margherita", 50));
    menuItems.add(new Pizza("Hawaii", 55));
    menuItems.add(new Pizza("Marinara", 70));
    menuItems.add(new Pizza("Meat Lovers", 70));
    menuItems.add(new Pizza("Calazone", 60));

    menuItems.add(new Burger("Burger", 60));
    menuItems.add(new Burger("Cheeseburger", 65));
    menuItems.add(new Burger("Baconburger", 65));

    menuItems.add(new Soda("Coca cola", 25));
    menuItems.add(new Soda("Coca cola light", 25));
    menuItems.add(new Soda("Fanta", 25));
    menuItems.add(new Soda("Faxe kondi", 25));   
    return menuItems;

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PizzaOrderingSystem extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {

        window.setTitle("Pizza ordering system");
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu orderMenu = new Menu("Order");
        orderMenu.getItems().addAll(new OrderMenu().getmenuItems());
        menuBar.getMenus().add(orderMenu);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(menuBar);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 300, 300);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
}

class OrderMenu {

    public ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems;

    public OrderMenu (){

        menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Margherita",50) );
        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Hawaii", 55));
        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Marinara", 70));
        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Meat Lovers", 70));
        menuItems.add(new Pizza("Calazone", 60));
    }

    public ArrayList<MenuItem> getmenuItems() {
        return menuItems;
    }
}

class Pizza extends MenuItem {

    Pizza(String name, int cost) {
        setText(name +" $"+cost);
        setOnAction(e-> System.out.println(name+ " piza ordered"));
    }
}
```

(Posting [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this one, makes help much faster and easier)

Comment: Hi c0der, I am sorry for not being clear enough. I find it hard to explain myself because I am really confused about everything with java, I am new and have never programmed before. I am looking for exactly what youre trying to do, but when I enter it in, it gives me the same error as it has when I have tried it using e.g. grid og vBox. It says in the line with " orderMenu.getItems().addAll(new OrderMenu().getmenuItems()); " that it is not applicable. arraylist cannot be converted to collection. Hope u can get some meaning out of this. Would like to upload a picture, but cant find the option.

Comment: 1.Take my answer, copy paste it in one file (PizzaOrderingSystem.java) and run. It should run with no errors. Modify it to your needs and see where and why it fails.  2. I don't understand what do you mean by " e.g. grid og vBox". 3. Post [mcve] to save all guessing and misunderstanding.

Comment: I edited my answer: added simple implementation of Pizza class

Comment: Ive also edited my post to try and make it a bit clearer what im looking for.

Comment: I can see that we have misunderstod each other because of my bad explanation! Im very sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: The "edited" question is a completely new one. the original question  had nothing to do with tables. I think a new post would have been more appropriate.

Comment: Ive made a new post.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems = new OrderMenu().getmenuItems();
```

Comment: Hi Mehdi, I understand that this gets the arraylist from the other class, but how to I show the content in e.g. an VBox or a grid, non of those will take ArrayLists because they are not a Node? or at least that is what I get from the error message.

Comment: @DorteKrogshede please show within your code what parts is ambiguous for you. If you ask your question concisely, I can help you faster!

Comment: Of course. Im very sorry for not being clear enough. Im simply just trying to get the arraylist from the one class shown in the main interface somehow, I have to make a GUI but i cant figure out what to use to show the content of the arraylist because it says that none is applicable to use with an arraylist. Im am very sorry for not being clear enough, but Im very vey new with java and its my first time programming, I find it very hard to understand the syntax and therefore also to explain myself.

Comment: @DorteKrogshede it's okay, if you want I can teach you the basics.

Comment: that would be great if you're able to do that. Ive followed a course at my university and an online course, but I simple dont seem to get it. I cant get around why, so if you have any suggestions on how to understand the syntax better I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: @DorteKrogshede please send me a message within my linkedin so that we can exchange contact info and numbers there -> https://www.linkedin.com/in/afsari